# 'get' undefined with $http in .service of AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Thanks to some experts out there who helped me a few hours ago, I could move on to the next level.
Here I face probably a trivial issue but for a novice like me, it is a difficult one.

As the title represents, I was returned with 'get' of undefined even though I was using $http.get which worked well in other function.

What am I missing or doing wrong? Could anyone help me?

[ERROR MSG]

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

[app.js]

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module('myProject', [
])
.service('ProjectService', function($http) {
    var pjts = {};
    this.$http.get("projects_read.php", {}). // I have'get' here.
    .then(function(response){
        var pjts = response.data;
        this.getProjects = function() {
            return pjts;  
        };
    });
    this.getProjects = function() {
        return pjts;  
    },
    this.getProject = function(id) {
        for (var i = 0; i < pjts.length; i++) {
            if (pjts[i].id === id) {
            return pjts[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}.bind(this))
})();
```

Thank you so much in advance and hope you have a great day!

Comment: use $http instead of this.$http

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it didn't work before so I put .this instead. Still, it does not work..

Comment: please share a plnkr if possible

Comment: Why do you have `.bind(this)` in the second line from the end? That's going to cause problems.

Comment: Yes, I left a comment after your answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, remove the `.bind(this)` from the end of your function. Aside from causing a whole slew of other potential problems, it is probably causing Angular's dependency injection to fail to inject `$http`.

Also, `$http` is just a parameter to your function. It's not added to `this` so you shouldn't call it on `this`.

Also, the `this` inside your `then` handler will not be pointing to where you want it to. If you want to use `this` inside there, assign it to another variable and use that inside the handler:

```
var self = this;
// v------ this removed
$http.get("projects_read.php", {}). // I have'get' here.
.then(function(response){
    var pjts = response.data;
    // v----- self here
    self.getProjects = function() {
        return pjts;  
    };
});
```

Comment: Alternatively, use arrow functions

Comment: I tried this way, but didn't work. BTW, what do you mean by use arrow function?

Comment: @JLRishe, I meant the 'get' undefined issue remains.

Comment: @JamesD Added a new paragraph to the beginning of my answer. Please make that change as well.

Comment: Thank you @JSRishe. I tried to remove it. Still, I could figure out why, so I created a plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/60nPQYDMT3VmopnDpTiv?p=preview    and I left a question in app.js. Hope this explains what I am missing.

Comment: @JamesD. Your code isn't working because you're trying to assign the books to the scope before the service has retrieved them. Fixed: http://plnkr.co/edit/GTsgxfMggQOQiYVglS55?p=preview

Comment: Thank you so much @JSRishe! It worked!! I have spent almost two weeks to figure this out, but now I think I know some more better than when I started! Really helped me! Thank you again and have a wonderful day!!!

Answer (score 1):

**$http** is just a passed param in service function , not bind to the scope of Service function.
So either you can use it directly (without `this`) like:

```
$http.get("projects_read.php", {}).then(function(response){
    var pjts = response.data;
    this.getProjects = function() {
        return pjts;  
    };
});
```

OR,

if you really want to use `this` syntax , then assign the param $http to some service scoped variable., Like:

```
var self = this;
self.http = $http;
self.http.get("projects_read.php", {}).then(function(response){
        var pjts = response.data;
        this.getProjects = function() {
            return pjts;  
        };
    });
```

also, replace all `this` with `self` to avoid loosing the correct scope., and no need to do `bind(this)`

Comment: Thank you for your work. Still, it does not work in both way.. what else could be wrong?

Comment: are you still getting same error `Cannot read property 'get' of undefined` ?, or different

Comment: Still the same, @anoop.

Comment: @JamesD.: there is typo in you program at `}.bind(this))`, it should be `}).bind(this);`, 
Further : if you go with one flag for `this` keyword, like : `var self = this;`, then there is no need to do `.bind(this)` also

Comment: Thank you @anoop. I tried to remove it. Still, I could figure out why, so I created a plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/60nPQYDMT3VmopnDpTiv?p=preview    and I left a question in app.js. Hope this explains what I am missing.

Comment: @JamesD.:  you need to move `$http.get()` call inside some function, see this updates [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/60nPQYDMT3VmopnDpTiv?p=preview)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157683/discussion-between-james-d-and-anoop).

Comment: Thank you @anoop. I think the link has been removed, but appreciate for your assistance!!! have a wonderful day!